# Hide line at 0 but not the empty one

Tags: excel, vba

I need some help regarding my Macro.

My issue is the VBA hide the empty rows as well.

Can someone help me, I just want to hide the 0 row not the empty?

Many thanks.

```
Sub HideRows()
Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim hide As Boolean
'loop through rows
For i = 32 To 262
    hide = True
    'loop in the row: B through AF column
    For j = 4 To 41
        'if we found value greater then zero, then we don't want to hide this row
         If Cells(i, j).Value > 0 Then
            hide = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j

    Rows(i).Hidden = hide
Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Hide Rows Containing Only Zeros

```vb
' Task: Hide rows where all cells contain the number 0.
Sub HideRows()
    
    Dim cValue, i As Long, j As Long
    
    For i = 32 To 262
        For j = 2 To 32 ' columns 'B' through 'AF'
            cValue = Cells(i, j).Value
            If VarType(cValue) = vbDouble Then ' is a number
                If cValue <> 0 Then Exit For
            Else ' is not a number
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
        Rows(i).Hidden = j > 32
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, Vbasic2008 but it's not working, And I think it's because not all the columns between B and AF contain a number some are just formatting. Actually, if columns D-I-Q and V are at 0 then hide the row. Do you think you can help with this please? Many thanks